# How to be notified when other app is drawing over my activity?

Tags: java, android

I am monitoring the activity actual runtime utilizing the lifecycle callbacks onPause and onResume.

However, there are other apps that can draw over my app, such as Facebook chat heads and these apps don't trigger onPause. How can I check for it?

I am timing the user actual work time on my activity.

```
private final Timer mTimer = new Timer();
private TimerTask mTimerTask;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTimeTaken++;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setTitle(mTimeTaken + "Seconds");
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, 0, 1000);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mTimerTask.cancel();
}
```